# Is there a way to implement SaxonJS higher order functions in the Node.js runtime environment (not JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, node.js, xslt, saxon-js

We have an ongoing project where we are porting over an older C# system that used custom functions to augment the XSLT processing, and we were planning on writing it in Node.js/saxon-js.

It seems [from the documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-12.xml) that event though the higher order functions feature is available to JavaScript SaxonJS, that might not be the case for the Node.js subset of it.

Is there an alternative to that, still in the realm of Node.js / server-side JavaScript runtime?

Comment: Node is based on the exact same JavaScript engine as Chrome.

Comment: Which part of the documentation exactly lets you infer this? In terms of XPath/XSLT SaxonJS should support higher-order functions the same in the browser as under Node.js, indeed if you run the SaxonJS command line tool `xslt3` you can do e.g. `xslt3 -t -xp:"random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(1 to 10)"` without problems.

Comment: Extension functions you could write for SaxonJ in Java or for Saxon .NET in C# is the feature that you might not find as well developed in SaxonJS but I am not sure why you would refer to that as higher-order functions. Please clarify whether your "custom functions" were done in XSLT or in C#.

Comment: @Martin My apologies -- I must be using the wrong technical term for what I'm really trying to convey. What we need is to be able to have custom logic written in JavaScript that can be executed from within the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The custom functionality was previously done in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 there is a rich built-in function library https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/, furthermore `xsl:function` since XSLT 2 allows you to implement more functions in XSLT/XPath itself (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#stylesheet-functions).

As for SaxonJS (tested with the current 2.5 release) and Node.js to call into JavaScript, the following is an example that works for me:

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

globalThis.test1 = function() {
  return new Date().toGMTString();
}

const xslt1 = `<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <test>{js:test1()}</test>
    <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

console.log(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
  transform(
    map {
     'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
     'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
    }
  )?output`,
  null,
  { params : { xslt: xslt1 } }
));
```

Output e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>Sat, 19 Aug 2023 14:35:00 GMT</test><!--Run with SaxonJS 2.5 Node.js-->
```

Documentation https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!development/global and https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!xdm/conversions, although there the `globalThis` use is not mentioned; I believe that is necessary for Node as there, contrary to client-side JavaScript, a global `function` or `var` statement does not create a global function or variable.

As for processing nodes, I would think it should be save to access the value with e.g. `data()` before passing to JavaScript, as in

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

globalThis.test1 = function(date) {
  return new Date(date);
}

const xml1 = `<root>
  <item>
    <name>item 1</name>
    <date>Sat Aug 19 2023 17:20:07 GMT+0200</date>
  </item>
</root>`;

const xslt1 = `<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>{js:test1(data())}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

console.log(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
  transform(
    map {
     'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
     'source-node' : parse-xml($xml),
     'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
    }
  )?output`,
  null,
  { params : { xslt: xslt1, xml: xml1 } }
));
```

I can't tell for sure how the DOM library used by SaxonJS under Node.js and with the (clojure?) compilation exposes the usual browser know/W3C/WHATWG defined DOM properties and methods; you might need to wait until someone from Saxonica answers that separately or you can consider to ask follow-up questions with more specific details.

As simple `textContent` property of an element node seems to work here:

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

globalThis.test1 = function(dateNode) {
  return new Date(dateNode.textContent);
}

const xml1 = `<root>
  <item>
    <name>item 1</name>
    <date>Sat Aug 19 2023 17:20:07 GMT+0200</date>
  </item>
</root>`;

const xslt1 = `<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:js="http://saxonica.com/ns/globalJS"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>{js:test1(.)}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

console.log(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
  transform(
    map {
     'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
     'source-node' : parse-xml($xml),
     'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
    }
  )?output`,
  null,
  { params : { xslt: xslt1, xml: xml1 } }
));
```

One final note: for readability and easy understanding above I have always used the XSLT as a JavaScript string and run XSLT by calling the XPath 3.1 function `fn:transform` with `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate`; once you have developed your XSLT code for SaxonJS, however, it is highly recommended to "precompile" to SEF, using e.g. `xslt3 -t -nogo -xsl:xslt1.xsl -export:xslt1.sef.json -relocate:on` and to then use `SaxonJS.transform`, passing in the the created `sef.json` file. That way you get much better performance.

Comment: Interesting. I had seen that documentation page previously, but understood it to mean that this functionality was only available within the browser runtime (i.e. "window" object being available, etc).

Comment: Is this feature also available to run custom XPath expression and capturing the value of specific nodes? We use lots of custom functions similar to the following:`<xsl:value-of select="xslHelper:FixPubDate(//item/versioncreated, //item/altids/itemid)" />`

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!xdm/conversions suggests an XDM node is passed as a DOM node to JavaScript; I think your main problem will be to figure how that is exposed under Node as in the browser the W3C or nowadays WHATWG DOM is rather stable/documented/known while SaxonJS under Node uses some library and I am not sure how well that library implements the DOM as known from the browser and how far it gets through the (clojure?) compilation. You might need to ask follow-up questions when you encounter specific problems.

Comment: I have added two more examples showing some use of nodes; I can't tell whether you can generalize the third example and expect all DOM properties or methods to be exposed by the DOM library used. Anyway, keep in mind that XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 can do a lot on its own, without needing extensions from C# or JavaScript.

Comment: @jpm, for your example, it would also be helpful to understand whether you used C# extensions with Microsoft's Xsl(Compiled)Transform and XSLT 1 or with Saxon .NET and XSLT 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about extension functions, not about higher-order functions.

Yes, you can write extension functions in Javascript to invoke from a Saxon-JS XSLT stylesheet running under Node.js.

Now the question becomes, what exactly are you trying to do, how are you trying to do it, and how is it failing?

As Martin says, if you are moving from Microsoft's XSLT 1.0 processor the first thing to do is to check whether you really need extension functions at all, because many things that needed extension functions in XSLT 1.0 can be done natively in XSLT 3.0.

If you do need to use extension functions, then it's a bit more complicated than in the browser because there is no simple "global object" to hang the functions on. Instead it's probably best to supply an object whose methods you want to call as an explicit stylesheet parameter.

Martin raised some questions about the DOM support in Node.js. SaxonJS has its own DOM implementation, forked some years ago from https://github.com/xmldom/xmldom, and nodes will be passed to your extension functions as Node objects from this library. The public methods of these objects should (if we got it right) be protected from any name-mangling by the Closure compiler. However, if you want to manipulate nodes, writing your functions in XSLT using `xsl:function` is usually a better option than writing them in Javascript.